# Does formal language theory have concepts corresponding to dependency grammars?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammar

If I am correct, [phrase structure grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_structure_grammar) in linguistics are the grammars for recursively enumerable languages.

Does formal language theory have concepts corresponding to [dependency grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar), the concept in contrast to phrase structure grammars in linguistics?

Thanks.